# How can I code a recursive call to a service that will call it at intervals?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code:

```
us.isConnected()
  .then(function (msg) { er.msg = msg }, function (msg) { er.msg = msg });
$interval(function () {
    us.isConnected()
  .then(function (msg) { er.msg = msg }, function (msg) { er.msg = msg });
        }, 20 * 1000);
```

It checks for a connection and then outputs a message.

Is there a way that I could simplify this code and make it recursive so I would not have to code the .then part more than once?

Comment: you could use a recursive function with $timeout instead so it executes immediately

Comment: @KevinB - I think this might be the solution but I am not sure how to implement that.

Comment: You will lose the control over the promise with recursive $timeouts, not counting the other possible problems that recursion brings.

Comment: @estus you won't lose control over the promise if you use `finally()` which also returns a promise.

Comment: @ryeballar But how will you use it to abort the recursion? Will `$timeout.cancel` take that promise, so you could do it outside of the loop?

Comment: Yep, here they are, good old flag variables.

Comment: If that is the case, how about enclosing the entire promise chain within the `$timeout` itself, that way you can cancel the `$timeout` with the promise it provided. [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YtTjbwyKMwma87Atg6bA?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$timeout` instead of relying on `$intervals` that may execute more than once `isConnected()` requests without waiting for the previously executed requests to finish.

```
var promise;

// execute testConnection()
testConnection();

function testConnection() {
  // run request initially
  return request().finally(function() {

    // runs the request recursively
    // and assign the timeout's promise
    // if you need to cancel the recursion
    return (promise = $timeout(request, 20 * 1000));

  });
}

// request if ui is connected
function request() {
  return ui.isConnected()
    .then(setErr, setErr);
}

// ser `er` object
function serErr(msg) {
  er.msg = msg;
}

// cancels the recursive timeout
function cancel() {
  $timeout.cancel(promise);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the asker will get benefit from diving too deep into promises, the code looks quite neat.

Answer (score 1):

```
var isConnected;

(isConnected = function () {
  us.isConnected()
  .then(function (msg) { er.msg = msg }, function (msg) { er.msg = msg });
})();

$interval(isConnected, 20 * 1000);
```

No recursion is necessary, unless it is necessary.

Comment: The problem here is that I want the isConnected to run immediately and then at intervals

Comment: The code above does this exactly. `(isConnected = function () { .. })()` is IIFE.